# Raw Query select data in Sequelize JS with Model Instances Not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelizeJs with raw query and reference `Users` instance but return data show all fields

```js
    // require Squelize
    const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize'); // i used v6.21.3

    // database connection
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('my_db', 'my_user', 'my_pass', {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql'
    });
    
    // Declare Users Instances
    const Users = sequelize.define("users", {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      username: DataTypes.STRING,
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
    });

    // Query Get users data
    async function getUsers() {
        let results = await sql.mysql_first_db.query("select * from users", {
            model: Users, // use Users instance
            mapToModel: true, // use true for mapped fields
        });

        // log results
        await console.log(results);
    }

    // call function getUsers
    getUsers();

    // results
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        username: 'ibomb',
        password: '2895f6eb811d9ba6c08e6565a7',
        name: 'bombkiml',
        email: 'bomb@bomb.com',
        family_name: 'ibomb',
        middle_name: 'kiml',
        given_name: 'kiml',
        isActived: '1',
        isDeleted: '0',
        createdAt: 2024-03-05T06:07:51.000Z,
        updatedAt: null
      }
    ]
```

The response results with `Raw Query` not Reference `Users` Instance.
So, I want to results like this.

```js
   // Results
   [
      {
        id: 1,
        username: 'ibomb',
        name: 'bombkiml',
        email: 'bomb@bomb.com',
      }
    ]
```

**Please tell me what happens ?**

and Thanks for solutions

Comment: Is there any difference in the result if you remove `mapToModel` option?

Comment: same result, bro

Comment: `results.map(x => x.get({ plain: true }))` returns the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the attributes you want like this:

```
 Model.findAll({
   attributes: ['id', 'username', 'name', 'email']
 });
```